# Set zlim in mplot3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

```
mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = fig1.gca(projection='3d') 

ax.plot(tab_C[0], tab_C[1], zs=0, zdir='z', label = "Projection de la trajectoire de C", color='k')
ax.plot(tab_M[0], tab_M[1], zs=0, zdir='z', label = "Projection de la trajectoire de M", color='r')

for i in range(0,len(tab_t)):
    ax.plot(tab_C[0][i:i+2], tab_C[1][i:i+2], tab_C[2][i:i+2], color=plt.cm.rainbow(255*i/len(tab_t)))
    ax.plot(tab_M[0][i:i+2], tab_M[1][i:i+2], tab_M[2][i:i+2], color=plt.cm.rainbow(255*i/len(tab_t)))
    
ax.legend()

ax.set_xlabel('I')
ax.set_ylabel('J')
ax.set_zlabel('K')

m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.rainbow)
m.set_array(tab_t)

plt.colorbar(m)
```

I've got this plot with my code

[image: My plot]

My problems are

- I want to set label for the color bar but ScalarMappale don't have the methode set_label()
- I want to set zmin=0 to see clearly the projection on the plan (0xy) but it seems that zmin here is 0.05 and when I do
  ax.set_zlim(bottom=0)
  It returns

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 117, in <module>
    ax.set_zlim(bottom=0) 
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 515, in set_zlim3d
    lims = self._determine_lims(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 476, in _determine_lims
    xmin -= 0.05
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Is there any way to solve my problems?

Answer (score 7):

the correct way of calling is: `set_zlim(min_value, max_value)`, if there are problems try also `set_zlim3d`

according to the documentation, `colorbar` object has a method `set_label`, see an example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html)

Comment: i've tried your suggest for set_zlim, it gave the same error. and for set_zlim3D it gave AttributeError: 'Axes3DSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_zlim3D'

Comment: and when I use colorbar.ColorbarBase, it gave: AttributeError: 'QuadMesh' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'

Comment: `cb=plt.colorbar(m)
cb.set_label('blabla')` works totally fine for me

Comment: `ax.set_zlim(0,40)` works as well. Maybe try adding `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D` in the beginning

Comment: 'set_ylim()' and 'set_xlim' work for me but 'set_zlim' always doesn't. I've imported Axes3D as well.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? If it doesn't work for you, then it might be a bug and it's worth contacting matplotlib developers